# CSS/HTML div width over resolution

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

I have to cut PSD file into CSS and HTML. The problem is container with background image has 1160px of width. This container have only background image on right side so I could be hidden on smaller resolution. Main content container have 996px so it's good.

I'm trying to do it this way:

- if resultion is more than 1160xXXX show whole image on right side,
- if resolution is less than 1160xXXX hide a smart part of image on the right side.

Image on the right side have to be always on the same place - its relative to the .container .inner which together looks nice.

My code:

```
.container {
    max-width:1920px;
    margin:0 auto;
    position:relative;
}
.container .background {
    background:black url("../img/woman.png") no-repeat scroll right top;
    max-width:1160px;
    overflow:hidden;
}
.container .inner {
    width:996px;
}
```

The goal is to put background image always in the same place and cut this image if resolution is less than 1160px. Any advices?

**EDIT:**

For no .container .background changing it's position depending on resolution... I don't want it - image have to be always in the same place.

Comment: Could you explain what exactly is happening now, because your css should do the trick (although I think the scroll is not needed)

Comment: you should use [media queries](http://css-tricks.com/css-media-queries/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use media queries like

```
@media only screen and (max-width:1160px){
  #something{
     some css
  }
}
```

You can read more about media queries [Here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Media_queries)

Comment: wow i was just adding that to DOK's answer, ^ this is exactly what you need :)

Answer (score 1):

One new approach often used for mobile and tablet browsers, is to **use pairs of images** of different sizes. In responsive design, for example, you can use the CSS `@media` to check the device window width, and return a larger or smaller image depending on the circumstance.

Comment: yup in order to make DOK's answer more complete, google CSS Media Queries